# Ruby time zone handling when merging data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Two sets of data need to be merged to create a new DateTime object

```
def mergeDateTime(date_to_merge, time_to_merge)
  DateTime.new(date_to_merge.year, date_to_merge.month,date_to_merge.day, time_to_merge.hour, time_to_merge.min, time_to_merge.sec)
end
```

querying `@signature = Signature.where('playtime_id = ?', 514).first` 
returns

```
Signature id: 834,[...], created_at: "2017-06-27 05:16:52"
```

and querying `@interruption = Interruption.where('playtime_id = ?', 514).first`
returns

```
Interruption id: 190, [...], pause: "2017-06-27 06:46:19"
```

but running

```
mergeDateTime(@signature.created_at, @interruption.pause)
```

returns

```
Tue, 27 Jun 2017 08:46:19 +0000
```

which is wrong as it interpreted the data at GMT +2 and should have generated

```
Tue, 27 Jun 2017 06:46:19 +0000
```

How can this presumption of timezone adjustment be neutered?  **and** take into account the offset of the timezone according to the date_to_merge date?

Answer (score 0):

[Specify the timezone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Zones.html#method-i-in_time_zone) with `in_time_zone`:

```
def mergeDateTime(date_to_merge, time_to_merge)
  date_to_merge = date_to_merge.in_time_zone('UTC')
  time_to_merge = time_to_merge.in_time_zone('UTC')
  DateTime.new(
    date_to_merge.year, 
    date_to_merge.month,date_to_merge.day, 
    time_to_merge.hour, 
    time_to_merge.min, 
    time_to_merge.sec
  )
end
```

Comment: This is returning the exact same result `Tue, 27 Jun 2017 08:46:19 UTC +00:00`

Comment: Close.  Functional answer is to invoke time zone on the object to be handled: `mergeDateTime(@signature.created_at, @interruption.pause.in_time_zone('UTC'))`

Comment: Updated answer to reflect @Jerome

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer points in the right direction, the moment of the conversion to UTC matters

```
ts_pause_raw = @interruption.pause.in_time_zone('UTC')
ts_pause = Time.parse(ts_pause_raw.to_s[11,8])
```

Then `def mergeDateTime(date_to_merge, time_to_merge)`can be called without further invocation of in_time_zone.

Occurring after, it is too late.